# Getting Disqus html code to show in source for SEO purposes

Tags: javascript, comments, disqus

Recently started using Disqus on a site & was wondering if there was any way possible to have it so the actual html code will show up in the source page?

I noticed this site is doing it.. http://adamkaras.com/blog/2009/06/24/disqus-custom-css-styling-in-3-easy-steps/

But I'm not sure how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WordPress Disqus plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/) and [Drupal's plugin](http://drupal.org/project/disqus) use the Disqus API to mirror all comments into their local databasees. There may be equivalent plugins for other CMSes, and it'd be fairly easy to implement in your own custom system as well.

Comment: Thank you. I was just looking at their API & thought that may be how it was done.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation about Drupal's plugin that supports your claim! I only found the opposite: https://drupal.org/node/1255208 and http://www.quora.com/Disqus/How-does-Disqus-use-an-iframe-while-maintaining-SEO-compatibility

Comment: @PascalKlein Given that this answer is three years old, I'd suspect the Drupal plugin and/or the Discus API has changed.